# How to specifiy shared super type as parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, variance

I need some help on this scenario:

A trait defines an shared interface with some methods.
One of the methods should look like this

```
 def fromConfig( config : Config):
```

Each implementation should override the method with something like:

```
  override def fromConfig(config: SubConfigA)
```

However, doing so gives "Method .. overrides nothing" error
even though the config stuff is defined as

```
  abstract class Config
  trait SubConfigA extends Config
  trait SubConfigB extends Config 
  ....
```

I remember, in Java you actually can define an interface as parameter,
and use sub-interfaces in subclasses for refinement.

Apparently the same does not work in Scala.

The code above is just a draft but the idea is passing 
specific configurations matching to a specific implementation 
of the shared interface.

Any idea or advice would be most appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
abstract class Config
trait ConfigA extends Config
trait ConfigB extends Config

trait FromConfigLoader[C <: Config] {
  def fromConfig(config: C)
}

class TestA extends FromConfigLoader[ConfigA] {
 def fromConfig(config: ConfigA) = ???
}

class TestB extends FromConfigLoader[ConfigB] {
 def fromConfig(config: ConfigB) = ???
}
```